# New York: Hole in basement floor?

Tags: basement, dehumidifier

***Disclaimer**: This may be a FAQ once I find the right terminology. Apologies for any time-wastage.*

In the basement of a single-family dwelling in NY state, I have this hole in the floor below the main floor-line. Several other properties have something like this or a drain.

1. Question 1: What is this officially called?
2. Question 2: For this class-of-hole - can I run a dehumidifier drainage hose directly in?

Sadly, I don't have enough distance pump-power to get a line from my dehumidifier to the slop sink, so trying to be creative...

[image: Basement Floor]

Comment: what happens when water goes in there?

Comment: What hoke? where is it

Comment: That is just a hole to pass the main water line.  It is not a drain or a place to let waste water in.  Some people would have that hole covered up/finish a lot better so only have a small opening to let the water pipe though.

Comment: Where do those white pipes go?  They look like drain lines.  Might be able to add a wye to one of them to drain the dehumidifier, but will let the plumbers say if it is possible(to code).

Comment: I presume we're looking straight down here? How about some light so we can see what's in that "hole". Here in the Midwest a lot of basements have "holes" called a "sump pit" to allow water that gets into the basement to collect and be pumped out. This doesn't appear to be a sump pit. Intentionally adding water to this will likely just make a mess in your basement.